# how can I show/hide some categories from the admin product page using woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've been trying to do this for a time, unfortunately I've found only solutions for the store(frontend) in cases the category is empty and so on.

What I basically want to do, is when I create a new product, at the Prodct Categories section [image]

I want to show/hide some categories.

So far I haven't found anything for this, any idea how can it be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out below code :

```
function is_edit_page($new_edit = null){
    global $pagenow;
    //make sure we are on the backend
    if (!is_admin()) return false;

    if($new_edit == "edit")
        return in_array( $pagenow, array( 'post.php',  ) );
    elseif($new_edit == "new") //check for new post page
        return in_array( $pagenow, array( 'post-new.php' ) );
    else //check for either new or edit
        return in_array( $pagenow, array( 'post.php', 'post-new.php' ) );
}


function so_28055266_filterGetTermArgs($args, $taxonomies) {
    global $typenow;

    if ($typenow == 'product') { 
        // check whether we're currently filtering selected taxonomy
        if (implode('', $taxonomies) == 'product_cat' && is_edit_page()) {
            //Add categories term ID that you want to show
            $cats = array(9,10,11,12); // List of category(term ID) that you want to add as an array

            if (empty($cats))
                $args['include'] = array(99999999); // no available categories
            else
                $args['include'] = $cats; //It will only show the category that you mentioned in above array
        }
    }

    return $args;
}

if (is_admin()) {
    add_filter('get_terms_args', 'so_28055266_filterGetTermArgs', 10, 2);
}
```

Let me know the output.

Comment: thanks for the help, unfortunately it returns me an empty box, I am using the ID of the category I want to show at the line of the code of $cats = array(MYID); but nothing, should I change something else?

Comment: sorry, i tried again some things, it worked now! (it had conflict with my previous code) is there any way to show the sub categories of the category without specify them one by one?